# Error con imagen descargada - PHP

Tags: php

estoy intentando descargar con PHP algunas imagenes en JPG.
Los enlaces funcionan ok, y realiza la descarga, pero a la hora de abrir el archivo me sale:

**'Fotos no puede abrir este archivo proque el formato no es compatible en este momento, o porque el archivo está dañado'**

```
$destino= '/var/www/html/test/custom/modules/test/';
$url = 'http://PaginaDondeSeEncuentralaImagen/enlace.jpg';
file_put_contents($destino .'/imagen.jpeg', file_get_contents(urlencode($url)));
```

El enlace está ok ya que cuando ingreso por la URL veo la imagen, pero cuando se me descarga a mi maquina remota no lo puedo abrir.

Comment: Hice una prueba en local y me sale `Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Pero quitando el `urlencode`, dejando solo `file_get_contents($url)` descargó una imagen correctamente.

Comment: Hola! Gracias. Si, yo llego a descargar la imagen correctamente, pero cuando queda en el directorio con el nombre - imagen.jpeg -  no me deja abrirlo. No sé si es un error del código

Answer (score 0):

has definido las cabeceras para poder enviar archivos en las peticione?
Dale una vistazo a este ejemplo para que te des una idea.

```
$img = "./ruta/imagen.jpg";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($img));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta estas otras opciones:

1- `file_get_contents` (dices no te funcionó)

```
file_put_contents($destino .'/imagen.jpeg', file_get_contents($url));
```

2- `fopen`

```
file_put_contents($destino .'/imagen.jpeg', fopen($url, 'r'));
```

3- `CURL` (ejemplo tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28506847/1545868) de SO Inglés)

```
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_FILE    => fopen($destino . '/imagen.jpeg', 'w'),
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
  CURLOPT_URL     => $url,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Hice pruebas con las 3 y las 3 descargaron un archivo correctamente.